# Using google api client in python, no matter what I do the same error pops up

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, credentials, google-api-python-client

Here's the error:

```
raise UnknownApiNameOrVersion(
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: youtube  version: v3
```

I am trying to access the YoutubeDataApi v3, and all of the places of I've looked (including running it through chat gpt) all say that the proper name and version are the ones im using. I have checked and rechecked all of my client information and it is all correct. I have also visited the discovery file it is pulling from, and it is there, the name and version.
File: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest
Here is my code if it helps:

```
import json
import random
import time
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from replit import web
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

app = web.app

def load_credentials():
    with open("client_secret.json", "r") as file:
        credentials_data = json.load(file)
    return Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(credentials_data)

credentials = load_credentials()
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# rest of code
```

If I'm an idiot or it's something else, please let me know.